# How can I undo git add files after git init

Tags: git, version-control

I have just added a bunch of files after I git init. Now I notice that I've made a mistake and want to undo all of them at once. How can I do that?

```
$ git init 
$ git add .
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .DS_Store
#   new file:   .gitignore
#   new file:   .idea/.generators
#   new file:   .idea/.name
#   new file:   .idea/.rakeTasks
#   new file:   .idea/DAM.iml
...
```

`git rm --cached <file>` will need to specify all files individually. I'd like to do it in a single command. Is it possible?

I did `git reset HEAD`, but it doesn't help.

```
$ git reset HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the right commands. (Except `reset` in this particular case because you have no HEAD yet - as there's no commits. But `reset` would usually work).

The only you miss is that Git can take glob patterns.

```
git rm --cached *
```

So this way you won't have to pass each file individually. Note that after your first commit you'll want to use soft `reset` for this (git rm would remove commited file too).

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but it doesn't work with subfolder. The output tells me to put -r (recursively) as `git rm -r --cached *`. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If its a new repository, you can just remove the **.git** folder inside your project and then initialize the git repository again.